# В чём подвох?? MySql

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            update_material = cursor.execute(f"UPDATE `material` SET `s` = {SET} WHERE `name` = {prod['material'][0]}, `s` = {prod['s']};")
            print("Успех")
            connection.commit()
```

ОШИБКА:

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', `s` = 25' at line 1")
```

Comment: получилось что?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### WHERE

Ошибка в синтаксисе выражения WHERE

Когда вы перечисляете условия выборки

- WHERE

  - name = {prod['material'][0]}
  - s = {prod['s']}

Вы их перечисляете через запятую.
Синтаксис SQL же предполагает что данные выражения будут связаны ключевыми словами `AND` либо `OR`

Соответственно вам необходимо заменить `,` на `AND` в выражении WHERE

#### Строковые значения и кавычки

Плюс, если Вы сами подготовливаете запрос и вручную вставляете в него значения - то оберните строковые значения кавычками.

Из двух полей одно точно было строковым и я его обернул

```
`name` = '{prod['material'][0]}'
```

поле `s` я пока оставил как есть, т.к. я не уверен в его типе, но если он строковый, то вам также стоит его обернуть кавычками.

За это наблюдение спасибо [@Sergey K.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/233811/sergey-k)

---

#### Итого:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            update_material = cursor.execute(f"UPDATE `material` SET `s` = {SET} WHERE `name` = '{prod['material'][0]}' AND `s` = {prod['s']};")
            print("Успех")
            connection.commit()
```

Comment: Также, скорее всего, надо взять значения в кавычки

Comment: @SergeyK. , да.. тут я пропустил, то что это обычная строка отформатированная

Comment: @SergeyK. внес дополнение в ответ

Comment: При работе с БД не рекомендуется формировать текст запроса, используйте подстановку, т.е. `cursor.execute("UPDATE material SET s = %s WHERE name = %s AND s = %s;", SET, prod['material'][0], prod['s'])`. Такой синтаксис, например, позволяет передать в INSERT сразу таблицу данных. И , вроде нет необходимости каких-то кавычек у имен полей и таблиц, если они не совпадают с ключевыми словами SQL.

Comment: @AlexTitov, Согласен со всем. Я описывал явные ошибки автора вопроса, которые приводили к завершению работы. На написание рекомендаций у меня не хватило сил, но обещаю их добавить, и дополнить ответ как доберусь до компьютера. –

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, причина в устаревшей версии MySQL. Попробуйте в sql-файле с помощью текстового редактора найти "TYPE = MYISAM" и заменить на "ENGINE = MYISAM". Либо просто обновите SQL и создайте БД заново. Но эта инфа с формуа 2013-2014 годов, так что может быть и неверной.

Comment: там две явные ошибки в SQL запросе. Сомневаюсь что обновление MySQL сможет исправить эту проблему.